# How to Chnage String Value to Italic

Tags: android, sqlite, textview

In My app i have a TextView and I display 2 string values in it.The string get from sqlite database and values display while running the app.

how can i change one value to Italic? it is possible?

```
dipSin.setText("  "+ value1 + "     ." + value2 );
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One way is to use html:

```
dipSin.setText(Html.fromHtml("<i>"+value1+"</i>"));
```

Just make sure that in the layout file, there is nothing that overwrites this style.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use :

```
dipSin.setTypeface(null, Typeface.ITALIC);
```

You can use other property like

```
dipSin.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD_ITALIC);
dipSin.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want your all texts to be italic, by using xml attribute.

```
android:textStyle="italic"
```